# TinyMCE scrubbing HTML in Umbraco

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, umbraco, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's `collapse` functionality in Umbraco, but when I edit the HTML of a page in the rich text editor (TinyMCE), the `data-` attributes are scrubbed when I save the page so the plugin doesn't work. I've followed [Allow any markup in the tinymce editor](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-%28tinymce%29/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor) with no effect. Can I stop TinyMCE scrubbing my HTML?

**EDIT:** I've reproduced the problem at http://fiddle.tinymce.com/BNcaab

Try pasting the code below into the HTML editor, then saving and clickig the HTML editor again.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle down" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
    <h4>Slide 1</h4>
    <span class="accordion-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco has TidyHtml run after a save/publish event and unfortunately doesn't 100% sysnc with the tinyMCE valid/invalid_elements. There are a number of html5 elements and attributes that get discarded and i believe some other basic elements like <scripts> (this is for the better, i say!) and <iframes>. I can't remember the exact list of elements that tidy will squash, but this is a problem that we ran into on our latest Umbraco 4.8.11 implementation and unfortunately had to resort to disabling tidy.
Disabling Tidy can be done in the [/config/umbracoSettings.config] with the following:

```
    <!-- clean editor content with use of tidy -->
    <TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent> <!-- gross but: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-(tinymce)/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor -->
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - it still rewrites my `<video>` tag and adds Flash `<object>` tags which prevent the video from working.

Comment: For those also unsure (like I was) this should be nested like this: `<settings><content><TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent></content></settings>`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, this setting is buggy: `<![CDATA[*[*]]]>` in the recent version of tinymce.
You will have to use the config option valid_elements and set the attributes as valid there.

Comment: I have this in my tinyMceConfig.config but the attributes are still removed:

    `....
 <validElements>
        <![CDATA[+a[id|data-toggle|data-parent|`

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it's in Umbraco.

Comment: this dos not matter, the html validator is the same: fiddle.tinymce.com